# How can I create dot configuration files in a docker container from a Dockerfile?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, dockerfile, configuration-files

New to docker here. 
My task is simple. I am trying to setup two config files that will end up in a docker container that will get created from a docker file.

In my laptop/machine have local file

*~/.path/file1* ,    with content:

`VAR1=BAR
 VAR2=FOO`

AND

*~/.file2* ,  with content:

`VAR3=VALUE1
 VAR4=VALUE2`

in my local macbook pro.

How can I create these files on the fly from a Dockerfile and have them ready in my Docker container that I can store in a container registry for later reuse?

This would help me greatly!

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to copy those exact files from your filesystem or only the content being defined in a Dockerfile and then being created in a Docker image?

Comment: @gesellix Only the content being defined in a Dockerfile and then being created in a Docker image

Comment: so, something similar to this should work:

```FROM alpine:edge \n
RUN echo "VAR1=BAR" > ~/.path/file1 \ \n
        echo "VAR2=FOO" >> ~/.path/file1 \n
...
```

(line breaks don't work in comments, I'll add a proper answer later)